# Authorize attributes not working in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

In my application i am using

```
 System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0
```

as my membership provider  and here my Account Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(string username,string password)
        {
            var result = Membership.ValidateUser(username, password);
            if(result)
            {

                var user = Membership.GetUser(username);
                var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(username);
                var isDistributor = roles.Any(x => x.ToUpper() == "DISTRIBUTOR");
                if (isDistributor) return RedirectToAction("ShowCurrentDistributor", "Distributor");
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["error"] = "Invalid login attempt";
            }
            return View();
        }
```

And my ShowCurrentDistributor action code:

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Distributor")]
        public ActionResult ShowCurrentDistributor()
        {

            var distributor = _distributer.GetDistributerbyEmail(User.Identity.Name);
            return View(distributor);
        }
```

But when i call **ShowCurrentDistributor** method, authorization not working. it always return back to my login form even i passed authentication with valid role( Distributor). Whats wrong with my code

Comment: fixed:  i added this line in  after if(result)
            { FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username,true);   .because validateuser onlyc checks username and password is valid it will not set any authentication token

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following line after successful validation:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username,true);
```

(answered in question comments by the original poster)